# Taking a norm of matrix rows/cols in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

The norm of a vector can be taken by

```
torch.norm(vec)
```

However, how to take a norm of a set of vectors grouped as a matrix (either as rows or columns)?

For example, if a matrix size is (5,8), then the rows norms should return a vector of norms of size (5).

Answer (score 10):

`torch.norm` without extra arguments performs what is called a Frobenius norm which is effectively reshaping the matrix into one long vector and returning the 2-norm of that. To take the norm along a particular dimension provide the optional `dim` argument.

For example `torch.norm(mat, dim=1)` will compute the 2-norm along the columns (i.e. this will compute the 2-norm of each row) thus converting a `mat` of size `[N,M]` to a vector of norms of size `[N]`.

To compute the norm of the columns use `dim=0`.